# Getting nested XML attribute value using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, traversal, linqpad

**Precursor**

The bit you don't really need to know, but might help in solving the issue, is that I am writing a series of C# statements in LINQPad, that gets a collection of records from an ELMAH (error logging system) database, extracts the XML (AllXml) field from each record and loads each extract into an XmlDocument. Ok, that seems fairly easy, but now I need to traverse each document and get a particular value from it.

**XML Structure Example**

*Note: I have removed any potentially confidential information here...*

```
<error type="System.Exception" time="2013-06-11T17:27:28.0122874Z">
    <item name="PATH_INFO">
      <value string="/foo/bar/thisIsTheValueIWant.aspx" />
    </item>
    <item name="PATH_TRANSLATED">
      <value string="C:\site\foo\bar\thisIsPotentiallyAnotherValueIMightWant.aspx" />
    </item>
    <item name="QUERY_STRING">
      <value string="meh" />
    </item>
</error>
```

Consider that this XML exists as a string, I have loaded this like so:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

**Problem**

It's not too difficult to get the value of a node, but in this instance, the value is stored as an attribute of a node, and I've no idea how to traverse that!

I basically need to get the `value` node nested in the `item` node with `name`, `"PATH_INFO"`, and then get the value of the `"string"` attribute.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using XmlDocument? It was superseded in 2008 by XDocument and XElement.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari, I'm using XmlDocument because I was unaware that it was superseded in 2008 by XDocument and XElement :-) ... As I'm now aware of this, maybe it's time for a little research and refactoring!

Comment: One of the many advantages of XDocument is that you don't have to learn XPath. You query it with LINQ in the same way you query any other kind of collection. In your case, the query is this: string result = (string) XElement.Parse (xmlString).Elements("item").Single(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "PATH_INFO").Element("value").Attribute("string")

Comment: @JoeAlbahari, thanks, that's definitely more promising than XmlDocument. Funnily enough, as we're discussing this, my manager sent me an email containing a shorter implementation using XDocument :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Once you have an `XmlNode` object, you can ask for its `Attributes` collection and get the one you want by name.

An example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNode itemNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/error/item[@name = 'PATH_INFO']");
if (itemNode != null)
{
    XmlNode value = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("value");
    String valueString = value.Attributes["string"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Works! :-) Thanks!. Might have helped had I not missed out a tag in the hierarchy! *FacePalm*

Answer (score 1):

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        var value = doc.SelectSingleNode("error/item[@name='PATH_INFO']/value/@string").Value;
```